# Clean the text data and save in csv format using Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, algorithm, text, data-cleaning

I have a text file of about 7000 sentences. Every sentence is in a new line. The sample format of my text file's data is given below. I want to change the format and clean the data using `python`.

`(input.txt)`

```
I\PP.sg.n.n am\VM.3.fut.sim.dcl.fin.n.n.n going\VER.0.gen.n.n to\NC.0.0.n.n school\JQ.n.n.crd .\PU
When\PPR.pl.1.0.n.n.n.n I\PP.0.y go\VM.0.0.0.0.nfn.n.n.n outside\NC.0.0.n.n ,\PU I\NST.0.n.n saw\NN.loc.n.n something\DAB.sg.y .\PU
I\PP.0.y eat\JQ.n.n.nnm rice\NC.0.loc.n.n .\PU
```

I want to change the format of the above data of the text file and want the below format in CSV.

`(input.csv)`

| **Sentences** | **Tags** |
| --- | --- |
| I am going to school . | PP VM VER NC JQ PU |
| When I go outside , I saw something . | PPR PP VM NC PU NST NN DAB PU |
| I eat rice . | PP JQ NC PU |

I have tried some approaches but nothing is working properly to get my desired format. I am really confused. It would be a great help for me if any kind soul can help me.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: For each line, use the `str.split` method to split on the spaces, then for each word, use https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match with the pattern `r"(.*?)\\(\w+)"` to get a match object with both the piece of the sentence and the pattern.  Put those into arrays.  Use `" ".join(some_array)` to turn arrays into space delimited strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python Code:**

```
txt = r"""
I\PP.sg.n.n am\VM.3.fut.sim.dcl.fin.n.n.n going\VER.0.gen.n.n to\NC.0.0.n.n school\JQ.n.n.crd .\PU
When\PPR.pl.1.0.n.n.n.n I\PP.0.y go\VM.0.0.0.0.nfn.n.n.n outside\NC.0.0.n.n ,\PU I\NST.0.n.n saw\NN.loc.n.n something\DAB.sg.y .\PU
I\PP.0.y eat\JQ.n.n.nnm rice\NC.0.loc.n.n .\PU
"""

for line in txt.strip().split('\n'):
    words, tags = [], []
    for wordtag in line.strip().split():
        splits = wordtag.split('\\', 1)
        words.append(splits[0])
        tags.append(splits[1].split('.')[0])
    print(f"\"{' '.join(words)}\",\"{' '.join(tags)}\"")
```

**Output:**

```
"I am going to school .","PP VM VER NC JQ PU"
"When I go outside , I saw something .","PPR PP VM NC PU NST NN DAB PU"
"I eat rice .","PP JQ NC PU"
```